# Create an array/list/collection of IDs in a column, cross-referenced to the rows each ID appears in

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have some data that I am trying to index so that I can have Excel go through it and apply various methods or look up various properties based on each "group" of IDs.

In column A I have the ID for a 'provider'. Each provider will appear anywhere between 1 and 4 times, depending on how many sub-units it has (1,2,3, or M, appearing in column B). The providers will always be consecutive (as in, if a provider appears 4 times, each one will be right after the next).

Thus, the first column will look like this, (transposed to save space): 30111,30111,30111,30111,30113,30113,30114,30114,30114,31308... etc.

I want to iterate through this column and "group" together these IDs so that I can then add to my macro to do actions to each group of identical provider id's. In other words I need to have some sort of index (in an array, list, collection, dictionary, or whatever) that says, the first ID includes rows 1-4, the second ID includes rows 5-6, etc.

Any ideas? I have been trying to use arrays, dictionaries, and collections so far with no success. I feel I am probably having the most trouble conceptualizing the correct solution to this problem.

I think a database might be a more useful solution but having something work in excel is a priority for me, as it makes the solution portable, easier to set up, understandable for more people, and potentially more reliable.

Comment: A dictionary keyed by ID, containing each ID's row numbers in a separate collection/array/comma-separated list?

Comment: The question is, how can I key by ID? As far as I can tell, I have to explicitly name each entry - IE, I cannot do dictProviders.Add(cell.value), I have to do dictProviders.Add("30111"), which makes doing it through a loop impossible. Even if I could do it that way, I can't implicitly name the array/collection/list that follows. As far as I understand anyway.

Comment: (I'm assuming you mean something like the following)  For each cell in range, dictProviders.Add(cell.value,cell.value) [end loop] For each item in dictProviders, ~create array with name dictProviders.Item~

Comment: How much data are you working with (ie, does the solution have to be efficient)?

Comment: @Blackhawk typically about 3000 rows, with about 750 different providers. Doesn't have to be hugely efficient, but looping through all cells too many times could be problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I meant by having a dictionary store collections which contain the row numbers:

```
'loop to fill dictionary
For Each cell In Selection
    id = cell.Value
    If Not dict.Exists(id) Then dict.Add id, New Collection
    dict(id).Add cell.Row
Next cell

'get the first id and read out its rows
id = dict.Keys(0)
For Each v in dict(id)
    Debug.Print v
Next v
```

I don't know how you got the impression that dictionary keys must always be string literals. But if you have a cell with value `30111`, `cell.Value` will be of type double, so after `dict.Add cell.Value, ...` the key `30111` will be in the dictionary, but `"30111"` (as a string) will not, and `dict("30111")` will just return empty. Maybe this was your issue? To avoid it you need to use `CStr()`.

Comment: Ah ok this makes some sense to me after a little bit of thought. I will try it out and post results.

Comment: OK bingo, I'm getting the row numbers returned so clearly that is working. Now I just need to iterate through all the IDs and do the formulas and formatting!  Thanks so much!

Comment: By the way, is there a way I can retrieve all the values stored in each dictionary entry at once? Say I want to grab all the rows from the first entry and calculate the sum from those rows in column W... is there a way to do that? Sorry to revive this a day later but I am struggling with this one!!

Comment: You would have to loop through the collection of row numbers (as in the second snippet), and use the loop to either add the cells' values or build a `Range` object with all the cells you want. If you go the latter route, it isn't too hard to build a class to wrap around all that.